# Why does MySQL server perform slower on RDS than on EC2?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I just made a benchmark testing with [`mysqlslap`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlslap.html) for the MySQL server on RDS and the MySQL server on an EC2 instance.

The following are my parameters and test result:

- MySQL version: `5.6.44`
- RDS instance type: `db.t3.large`
- EC2 instance type: `t3.large`
- RDS storage type: `General Purpose (SSD)`
- EC2 AMI: `amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20190618-x86_64-gp2`
- RDS parameter group: `default.mysql5.6`
- RDS Multi AZ: `No`
- RDS region: `tokyo`
- EC2 instance region: `tokyo`
- EC2 EBS encryption: `enabled`
- EC2 EBS storage size: `100GB`
- RDS storage size: `100GB`
- RDS performance insights: `disabled`

Both MySQL servers on RDS and the EC2 instance are newly created. They don't contain any data before running `mysqlslap`.

The EC2 instance is also newly created. I only installed MySQL server on it. I didn't change anything else on the instance.

`mysqlslap` was run from my local MacBook Pro.

The MySQL server on the EC2 instance is installed by running `sudo su &&
wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch.rpm &&
rpm -ivh mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch.rpm &&
yum install mysql-server &&
/etc/init.d/mysqld start`

Here's the benchmark testing result:

```
# MySQL on RDS benchmark testing result:
mysqlslap --host=loadtest.xxxxxxxxx.xx-xx-x.rds.amazonaws.com \
  --user=myusername \
  --password=mypassword \
  --create-schema=load_test_table \
  -vv \
  --concurrency=50 --iterations=5 \
  --auto-generate-sql 

Building Create Statements for Auto
Building Query Statements for Auto
Parsing engines to use.
Starting Concurrency Test
Loading Pre-data
Generating primary key list
Loading Pre-data
Generating primary key list
Loading Pre-data
Generating primary key list
Loading Pre-data
Generating primary key list
Loading Pre-data
Generating primary key list
Generating stats
Benchmark
Average number of seconds to run all queries: 4.362 seconds
Minimum number of seconds to run all queries: 3.134 seconds
Maximum number of seconds to run all queries: 7.581 seconds
Number of clients running queries: 50
Average number of queries per client: 0
```

```
# MySQL on EC2 benchmark testing result:
mysqlslap --host=<ec2's ip address> \
  --user=myusername \
  --password=mypassword \
  --create-schema=load_test_table \
  -vv \
  --concurrency=50 --iterations=5 \
  --auto-generate-sql 

Building Create Statements for Auto
Building Query Statements for Auto
Parsing engines to use.
Starting Concurrency Test
Loading Pre-data
Generating primary key list
Loading Pre-data
Generating primary key list
Loading Pre-data
Generating primary key list
Loading Pre-data
Generating primary key list
Loading Pre-data
Generating primary key list
Generating stats
Benchmark
Average number of seconds to run all queries: 2.196 seconds
Minimum number of seconds to run all queries: 2.000 seconds
Maximum number of seconds to run all queries: 2.445 seconds
Number of clients running queries: 50
Average number of queries per client: 0
```

The CPU Credit Balance on both MySQL servers are above 0 when running `mysqlslap`. So the problem of running out of CPU Credit Balance doesn't exist.

As you can see from the benchmark result, the MySQL server on RDS runs about twice as slow as the MySQL server on an EC2 instance.

Why does this happen?

Are there any parameters that I can configure to make the MySQL server on RDS performs as good as the that on an EC2 instance?

[Here](https://pastebin.com/Wf3VPfTq) is the output of `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;` of EC2 MySQL.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/87qG2zRQ) is the output of `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;` of RDS MySQL.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/FEHShDP4) is the result of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` of EC2 MySQL after running 3 benchmark tests.

And [here](https://pastebin.com/RftNfu0E) is the result of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` of RDS MySQL after running 3 benchmark tests.

I've found that disabling `sync_binlog` on RDS MySQL improves its performance. But RDS MySQL's performance is still worse than EC2 MySQL after doing this.

Comment: I believe RDS uses encrypted EBS storage which should be slower than basic EC2 EBS (non-encrypted), perhaps try using an encrypted EBS volume with your MySQL instance

Comment: I just turned on the encryption for the EBS of the EC2, and ran mysqlslap against it. And the result didn't change much. `Average`: 2.167 seconds. `Minimum`: 1.742 seconds. `Maximum`: 2.433 seconds.

Comment: @brian Use of pastebin.com or similar storage will avoid the 30,000 character limitation.  Post from RDS and EC2 text results SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; and SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  for comparative analysis.

Comment: @Brian Could you also post from RDS and EC2 text results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; for comparative analysis.  Thanks for posting both SGV.

Comment: Hi, @WilsonHauck, I've posted the results of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` of both RDS and EC2 at the end of the question.

Comment: See https://pastebin.com/87qG2zRQ, and https://pastebin.com/Wf3VPfTq.

Comment: @Brian The two links above are for July 3, 19 SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES, need SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; rather than another copy of same info from two days ago.  Please view my profile, Network profile for contact info.

Comment: @WilsonHauck. Sorry I didn't read your texts clearly. I've posted the output of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` of both MySQL servers in the question. Thank you for your reminder.

Comment: Please run your benchmarks 3 times on each machine and then POST the ECS and RDS SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; reports.  It is not uncommon to take more than one attempt to get data needed.  You are fine.  Typically we ask for SGS after 24 hours of uptime.  In your case, after 3 benchmark runs will be reasonable.

Comment: Hi, @WilsonHauck, I've run 3 tests before executing `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`. You can click on the links in my question to view the output of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`.

Comment: @Brian If you will compare the EC2 to RDS SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; reports line by line, you will see that RDS has binary logging turned ON, RDS has many com_flush events (usually causes more reads than necessary), innodb_data_read, reads, writes, written are much higher, SSL was OFF in EC2, there are many other areas with more activity in RDS than used in EC2. Config of read_rnd_buffer_size was doubled, likely caused most of the slow down.  Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile with contact info.  If you would like to review in depth, get in touch.